# Query to return zero if nothing exist

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a table With `currency`, `paymenttype` and `invoiceamount`. I have to write a query to get `currency`, `paymenttype` and total `invoiceamount` made.

This is pretty simple with group by. But actually I have three payment types - 0, 1, 2. The data in the table is

```
    Currency   PaymentType Invoice Amount
    Aaa.        0.           100
    Aaa.        1.           200
    Aaa.        1.            50
    Bbb.        0.           150
    Bbb.        1.           100
    Bbb.        2.           100
```

My query is

```
Select currency, paymenttype, sum(invoiceamount) as total
from table 
group by currency, paymenttype
```

Result

```
      Currency  paymenttype total
      Aaa.       0.          100
      Aaa.       1.          250
      Bbb.       0.          150
      Bbb.       1.          100
      Bbb.       2.          100
```

As Aaa. does not have `paymenttype` 2 it should also show a row with 0 value like below.

```
      Aaa.      2.     0
```

How to do this?

Comment: Sqlfiddle with data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ccaa/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the list of payment types and currencies are known, you can do this with CTEs.

```
with paymenttypes as (
  select 0 as ptype,
  Union select 1 as ptype,
  Union select 2 as ptype ), 
currencies as 
( select 'Aaa' as currency
  union
  select 'Bbb' as currency ),
sourcedata as (
  select currency, ptype as paymenttype, 0 as amount
  from currencies, paymenttypes
  Union all
  select * 
  from data)
select currency, paymenttype, sum(amount)
from sourcedata
group by currency, paymenttype;
```

It basically creates a Cartesian product of all currency, paymenttype pairs with a 0 amount, then joins it with the source data.

If your lists of payment types and currencies are all in lookup tables, then substitute them in.

Also note there are other ways, using `COALESCE` etc.

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ddce/17),

Comment: You could also use `from currencies cross join paymenttypes left join source ... group by ...` (and not use the source data and union at all.)